# The following signature scheme secure or not

Tags: signature

Assume there are two secret keys on server $x,y \in Z_p$. $p$ is a prime number.

He wants to prove that the message is sent from him.

He divides the message into two parts. $m_0, m_1$ and computes

$s=H(m_0)x+H(m_1)y$.

Users know $xP,yP$ where $P$ is an element of cyclic additive group of $G_1$.

If they know the message, they can easily check that $$H(m_0) xP+H(m_1)yP=sP$$

It seems work well. However, I wanna know what kind of proof should be used for that case.

Moreover, what kind of attack can exist? May be forgery of $s$ value.

Answer (score 1):

This is insecure.  Given two signatures, secret values $x$ and $y$ can be recovered.

Specifically, let $s = H(m_0) \cdot x + H(m_1) \cdot y \pmod p$ and $s' = H(m'_0) \cdot x + H(m'_1) \cdot y \pmod p$.  We have a system of two equations with two unknowns.  Hence, we can find $x = \dots$ and $y = \dots$